# How do I set up a scanner object in Java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to write a program that will read in a file of students academic credit data and create a list of students on academic warning.

I first need to set up a Scanner object to read from the input file. I am new to Java and I need step by step instructions.

Comment: Oracle gives pretty neat examples with the Scanner API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: A tip for more experienced coders are to put the Scanner object in a "utility class" i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75674577/11211041 or in a Singleton class i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29323215/11211041

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is often to do a little research before asking a question, e.g. use google, but since this is your first question, I assume, I will just give you the answer

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filename));
```

Comment: thank you, I'm just starting to learn Java and am also new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("filename.extenstion"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning of your program, make sure you have

import java.util.Scanner;

as your first line. Continuing, you should create a scanner in your program.

// Create a Scanner
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);