# How to use the same Scanner across multiple classes in Java

Tags: java, class, java.util.scanner

I have a program that uses multiple classes, I want the other classes to be able to access the same scanner that I have declared in the main class.

I assume it would be done using some sort of get method, however I am unable to find any resources to help me.

Here are the Scanners that I have made in my main class:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter a filename");
String filename = in.nextLine();
File InputFile = new File (filename);

Scanner reader = new Scanner(filename);
```

The reader Scanner is the one I want to be able to access across the other classes in my program.

Can anyone give me some guidance on how to do this?

Comment: This would seem to be somewhat fragile as another `class` could `close()` the `Scanner` and break everything - no? Maybe you should read the file into memory? Or is it very large?

Comment: one option would be to declare reader as a static field in your main class

Comment: another option would be to inject reader into other objects created from main class (assuming that main class is responsible for all the wirings)

Comment: @SergeyPauk How would I go about doing this, as I have indeed used objects to call other methods in the other classes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use `public static final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);` in you `main` class.
After that you can call it from anywhere by `MainClassName.in`.

Also, be careful with arguments you pass to Scanner. I guess you wanted to put `InputFile` into `Scanner`, rather than `filename` =)

```
File InputFile = new File (filename);
Scanner reader = new Scanner(filename);
```

Comment: So just do this with the Scanner that I have already defined, ie the "reader"?

Comment: Yes. You can declare your local field `public static Scanner reader` in `MainClass`, initialize it from you code and use it from anywhere. But be careful with closing this resources.

Comment: I cannot seem to call the Scanner into another class using the way you suggested, I am getting an error : "not a statement"

Comment: First, you need to declare local public static field in you `MainClass` like this: `public static Scanner reader;`. Second. You need to initialize it from your code, like this: `reader = new Scanner(filename);`. And, finally, you can call it from any other class like this: `MainClass.reader.nextLine()`. Beware of null pointers and resource closing.

Comment: Okay I've done this however now the Scanner is not correctly Scanning the file, before I had written a simple program that counted the number of spaces in a file however now it keeps saying there are 0 spaces, which is incorret

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74016/discussion-between-samolivercz-and-ar4ers).

Comment: I have just stumbled across another problem, it can only do one class at a time.

Answer (score 2):

There are so called [design patterns](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/) that help you to deal with such daily issues. They show up best practises.

You are looking for something like a [Singleton](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/singleton_pattern.htm), an instance of a class that is unique to your software echosystem.

For your example, you can do something like this:

```
public class MyScanner{
   private static MyScanner instance = new MyScanner();
   private MyScanner(){
       // init the scanner
   }

   //Get the only object available
   public static MyScanner getInstance(){
      return instance;
   }

   public void read(File f){
      // read your file
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question about dependency injection: here's a rough idea of [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (via constructor):

```
public void wire() {
    ...
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(filename);
    ClassA objectA = new ClassA(reader);
    ClassB objectB = new ClassB(reader);
    ...
}
```

class A (class B would have a similar constructor):

```
public class ClassA {

    private Scanner reader;

    public ClassA(Scanner reader) {
        this.reader = reader;
    }
    ...
}
```

So the idea is that you create and wire up your objects in wire() method.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using the great [Singleton](https://www.baeldung.com/java-singleton) solution like in [Remo Liechtis answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29323215/10749567) would be to use:
a **private static field** in a new or existing *"utility class"* e.g. "IO".

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IO {
    private static final Scanner s_scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static Scanner getScanner() {
        return s_scanner;
    }

    public static void closeScanner() {
        s_scanner.close();
    }
}
```

And then use the Scanner object by calling `IO.getScanner()`.
E.g.:

```
IO.getScanner().nextLine()
```

or (for readability assign) the IO Scanner to a **private static field**.
E.g.:

```
private static final Scanner s_scanner = IO.getScanner(); // Get Scanner from IO Class  
s_scanner.nextLine()
```