# Is there any way I can use a Scanner object in a different class?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, user-input

So I have a simple Scanner object:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
```

I am trying to use this Scanner object inside a method that I have declared in a different class. Is there anyway this can be done? I have also tried using:

```
public static final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

but this didn't really help

Comment: Use a "utility class" i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75674577/11211041 or a Singleton class i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29323215/11211041

Answer (score 5):

```
public static final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

As you have declared `Scanner` instance as `public` and `static`. So you access it using the Class reference.

Code in the other class.

```
String intpu = ClassName.scan.next();
```

`ClassName` is the name of the class in which it is defined.

There could be other ways of achieving this:

1. Pass this to method of the other class where you want to use it.
2. If you define `Scanner` instance as member of the class, then create the instance of class and access it using the getter method.
3. You can create a fresh instance of the `Scanner` in the other class.

Comment: When I try to do it this way, it doesn't compile and says illegal start of expression. Do you think the problem could be because I'm using this Scanner object in the class that it is defined and in the other class?

Comment: @Subhan How are you using it? Possibly you are trying to read a input and initialize a class member, while defining a class. You need to use this in any method. You cannot call instance method in the member declaration. `static` method can be called.

Answer (score 3):

A common design pattern to address this is dependency injection. One form of dependency injection is called constructor injection. For this, create a constructor which accepts the object the class depends on. Then when you instantiate that class, you pass in the object you would like it to operate on (in your case your scanner).

**Example**

`Main` - Caller class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        AnotherReader anotherReader = new AnotherReader(scan);
        anotherReader.readSomething();
    }
}
```

`AnotherReader` - class which requires a `Scanner` dependency:

```
public class AnotherReader {           

    Scanner scan;                      

    public AnotherReader(Scanner scan) 
        this.scan = scan;              
    }                                  

    public void readSomething(){       
        String line = scan.nextLine(); 
        // Do something                

    }                                  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the Scanner object's reference to that Method in the call.
something like `method(Scanner sc)`

Answer (score 0):

You could try `inheritance`:
Super Class:

```
public class superclass
{
     Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in); 
     //scanner object declared globally
     //constructor
     //other methods etc.
}
```

Sub Class:

```
public class subclass extends superclass
{
//the scanner object can be inherited
}
```

Using inheritance,the subclass can inherit the scanner object in the super class.
I hope this works.Please let me know if something goes wrong.

Can also be done without inheritance(without extending):

- Simply create the object of superclass in the concerned subclass method as:

  ```
   superclass ob=new superclass();
   //created superclass object
   String takeIN= ob.scan.next(); 
    /*refers to scanner object in superclass  because scanner object is declared a field(global object) in superclass.*/
  ```
- Following your example,if the scanner object in superclass is made static,you can simply use it like:

  ```
   Scanner takeIn=superclass.scan.next();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

My way of solving this problem is to add a Scanner parameter to the method I am calling of the class that needs to use the Scanner, and then pass the scanner variable as an argument when calling the method.

My main method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        CalledClass cC = new CalledClass();

        cC.testMethod(input);
    }
}
```

CalledClass.java:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalledClass
{
    public void testMethod(Scanner x)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter anything");
        String myString = x.next();
        System.out.println(myString);
    }

}
```

It's not the prettiest thing, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it:

1. Create MyScanner.java in a new package (in this case: mypackage)

   ```java
   package mypackage;

   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class MyScanner
   {
       static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

       public static String scan()
       {
           return scan.next();
       }

       public static String scanLine()
       {
           return scan.nextLine();
       }

       public static int scanInt()
       {
           return scan.nextInt();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use it anywhere by (static) importing all methods from MyScanner class of mypackage.

   ```java
   package yourpackage;

   import static mypackage.MyScanner.*;

   public class Main
   {
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
           System.out.print("put an integer : ");
           int a = scanInt();
           System.out.println("int a = " + a);
       }
   }
   ```

If you don't want to use static import, change `import static mypackage.MyScanner.*;` in MyScanner.java to `import mypackage.MyScanner;`. By doing this, you cannot call your scanner methods directly anymore, you need to specify the class containing the methods. For example: `MyScanner.scanInt()`, `MyScanner.scan()`.